# Temporary Table and Collation Issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My server database default collation is `Arabic_CI_AS`. In my application, I am never setting collation anywhere. But when I run this simple SQL,

```
CREATE TABLE #TempProductInventory
(
    PID int 
    ,InvTypeValue nvarchar(MAX) 
    ,InvTypeKey nvarchar(MAX) 
                        );

SELECT * 
FROM    #TempProductInventory TP
INNER JOIN dbo.[Sources] S ON (S.Code = TP.InvTypeKey)
```

I am getting,

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_CI_AS" in the equal to operation. When I un,
```

When I run,

```
SELECT col.name, col.collation_name FROM  sys.columns col WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Sources')
```

I will get,

```
name    collation_name
ID         NULL
Code       Arabic_CI_AS
```

Comment: Have you recently changed the server collation? TempDB is only created when the instance is started, so changing the server collation will not change the collation of the TempDB until the instance is restarted. What do you get if you run `SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE Name = 'tempdb';`?

Comment: try this CREATE TABLE #TempProductInventory(
    PID int 
    ,InvTypeValue nvarchar(MAX) 
    ,InvTypeKey nvarchar(MAX) 
                         Collate "Arabic_CI_AS")

Comment: @GarethD, the problem is that the database collation is arabic but the server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS? Nothing changed

Comment: @GarethD, its' `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will set the collation of temporary table to the one that you specify.
Most likely reason for this happening is as stated by GarethD that temp database collition is set not to `Arabic_CI_AS`.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempProductInventory( PID int ,InvTypeValue nvarchar(MAX) ,InvTypeKey nvarchar(MAX) Collate "Arabic_CI_AS")
```